# accessing variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following:

```
    public ActionResult GetRpt(string pNum)
    {
      string dirPath = "C:\\Folder1";
      string pvtResult =  GetType1Report(pNum);
    }

    private string GetType1Reportt(string paslNum)
    {
      string dPath = dirPath;          
     }
```

I need to access dirPath from within GetType1Report.

I get a mesage that dirPath does not exist in GetPReport.

What is the best way of accessing dirPath from withing GetPReport? I was thinking about having this as a public static but wasn't sure if this is the best way of going about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a `public static` variable for this.  If you declare the variable as `private` outside of your methods, you'll still be able to access the variable within your methods.

```
public class myClass
{
    private string dirPath;

    public ActionResult GetRpt(string pNum)
    {
      dirPath = "C:\\Folder1";
      string pvtResult =  GetType1Report(pNum);
    }

    private string GetType1Reportt(string paslNum)
    {
      dPath = dirPath;          
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Send it as a variable to GetType1Reportt?

```
private string GetType1Reportt(string paslNum, string dirPath)
{
    string dPath = dirPath;          
}
```

Comment: much cleaner and accurate answer +2

Comment: gotta show them how to use the method, because judging by the question I doubt they know

Comment: absolutely. Anyone looking at the function knows exactly where the value comes into play. The problem with class-level variables is that its not always obvious where they get manipulated etc. although in fairness modern development environments mitigate that. I'd go a step further here and make GetType1Report static, again to make it clear to the reader that the method has no dependence on instance variables.

Comment: @PeteH Saying to make it static is implying a lot. We cannot advise on that because we don't know what the actual method is doing and the code structure.

Comment: @ Stan R. Fair Enough, I made my comment purely based on the posted snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Is to pass the variable

```
public ActionResult GetRpt(string pNum)
{
  string dirPath = "C:\\Folder1";
  string pvtResult =  GetType1Report(pNum, dirPath );
}

private string GetType1Reportt(string paslNum, string dPath)
{

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass your variable into the method.
I would also advise against hardcoding a local path. What happens when you run this on a PC that doesn't have "C:\".

```
  public ActionResult GetRpt(string pNum)
    {
      string dirPath = "C:\\Folder1";
      string pvtResult =  GetType1Report(pNum, dirPath);
    }

    private string GetType1Reportt(string paslNum, string dirPath)
    {
      string dPath = dirPath;          
     }
```

Comment: ??? try to be more constructive we all have to start somewhere at least the OP has shown some effort

Comment: also how is advising the OP to hit C# books and watch some videos not being constructive?

Comment: you made the statement of not trying to be mean which can be view as being mean.. just stating my Opinion thanks Stan

Comment: i guess i made the assumption that he hasn't hit the books yet. I'll edit my answer.